# How to write a bash script to Quit the program?

Tags: bash, unix, exit

I am writing a bash script which contains a menu and one of the options in the menu is to quit the program. The code I have written looks something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome..."
echo "Chose an option :"
echo "option 1.."
echo "option 2.."
.........
echo "Quit the program "
```

I don't know how to give my strings functions so I'm trying to figure it out by understanding how to quit the program and how the code is written for it.

Comment: `read answer ; case $answer in 1) echo Got a 1 ;; 2) echo Got a 2 ;; 3 ) echo Got a 3 ;; [Qq]* ) echo Qutting ; exit ; esac` is a start. But read about the shell `select` feature, Search here with `[bash] select esac done`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use "exit" command.

There's an example here on what i found first in Google: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-exit/

Also you can exit with a Status code.

Comment: Yes but how would I write the exit command attaching it to the String, meaning if the user types in the number 4, it automatically quits the program?

Comment: @Sara `echo` is printing out whatever you type in the command. If you want to choose & exit, learn about user input: https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php
Then create an if-else condition. For ex: input is `4` then `do` `exit`